# Dropdown Menu get cut off

Tags: css, html

I have a drop down menu and it seems to be cut of due to the parent div i.e if i increase the height of the parent div, the drop down menu seems to come visible. please help. and below is my code:

**MarkUp**

```
<div id="main-navigation" class="container">
    <div class="menu rounded">
        <ul id="navigation" class="l_tinynav1">
            <select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-navigation .menu ul 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D51386;
    border-left: 1px solid #D51386;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #D51386;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 38px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 98%;
}

 #main-navigation .menu li 
 {
     border-left: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
     border-right: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
     float: left;
     height: 38px;
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
 }
```

Comment: I added some options to the select dropdown and closed your list tag and it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XLH5U/.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It may be that you have `overflow:hidden;` on one of wrap divs `.menu` `.rounded` `#main-navigation` or `.container`, check them.

Comment: thanks the parent container had the overflow set to hidden and changing it to visible solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

On inspecting your site, I found that you're using `ul` and `li` as custom dropdown menu.  Thr reason for cut off is the the `width` of `.va_sort_list_wrap`.

Try changing it to

```
.va_sort_list_wrap {
width: 132px;
}
```

Comment: @user2725936 can  you be more specific.  like provide a screenshot or make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @user2725936 I was sure it was a css conflict.  I found it, but too late.  Anyway you fixed it :)