# Dropdown menu being cuttoff

Tags: css, html

I have a drop down menu and it seems to be cut of due to the parent div. It becomes visible if the parent div height is increased. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you consider it [Dropdown Menu get cut off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491685/dropdown-menu-get-cut-off)  You have already asked it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `overflow: hidden` from `#masthead .row`

```
#masthead .row {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#masthead .row {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Great thanks..changed overflow to visible in #masthead .row and it solved the problem..great thanks